# Do not scroll ListView when cutsom view is touched

Tags: android, listview, custom-view

I've created a custom view on which you can draw a path with your finger. It extends View class.

When I use it inside a ListView as one of its items if a user touches custom view the ListView is scrolled. How can I prevent this from happening?

I suppose I need to get focus somehow on my custom view. But I don't know how.

**Update:**

I found possible solution. In my custom view's `onTouchEvent(Motion event)` method I've placed `getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);`.

Without this the event queue when user touches custom view looked like this:

1. MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
2. MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE
3. MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE
4. MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL

When I receive `MotionEvent` with code `MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL` the `ListView` starts to scroll.

Comment: Can you get the index of the view from the adapter you are using ? Because, if you can, then it is just a matter of `setSelection()`.

Comment: @Swayam The view also contains several other views appart from custom view. `setSelection()` selects a row. This is not what I am needed.

Comment: Forgive me for being naive, but if you select the row containing the custom view, shouldn't that do the trick for you ?

Comment: @Swayam I don't need to select the row. I need to prevent listview from scrolling when I touch custom view. If you select a row the listview still is going to be scrollable, isn't it?

Comment: Oh okay okay.. I didn't really understand your problem until now. I will have a look iand try to make it work. Until then, all the best to you.

Answer (score 3):

Setting `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)` within child's `onTouch(View, MotionEvent)` method works:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewGroup item = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        Button button = (Button)item.findViewById(R.id.list_item_btn);
        button.setText("button " + position);

        button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                listView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                return false;
            }

        });

        return item;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. For me, calling `v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);` worked, to keep it independent of the actual ListView instance.

Answer (score 0):

**I think u should also extend the ListView widget .**

As u say ,when u touch the custom view ,the listview will scroll.
when u touch the custom view, the touch event will dispatch along the view hierarchy ,
I think listview may eat the touch event.
so ur customview can not receive the touch event.
if ur have not understand the dispatch of the touch event.
u can read this [Managing Touch Events in a ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html)

at last.
I suggest u extend the ListView and override the *onInterceptTouchEvent()* method.
u can decide if ur ListView want to handle the touch event in the *onInterceptTouchEvent()*.
when u judge the touch should be handle by the drawPathView,
u can let the ListView dont intercept it.
so ur drawPathView can get the toch event .
and also the listView will not scroll

Comment: I don't thing this approach wroks for me. First of all I am able to draw very short line on the custom view, so it receives touch event for a short period but than loses the focus. Secondly, Buttons, for example, prevent ListView from scrolling: if you touch a button on a listview and try to scroll, this won't happen. So somehow it works there correctly.

Comment: ok. I see.
I think ListView start scroll after you have moved more then a distance in vertical 
so u can draw sort path ,when u draw the sort path ,the distance you have moved less then the trigger distance.

if u moved the distance more than the trigger distance the ListView start scroll.

do u think so?

Comment: I see your update message . I suggest u to read the article which I metioned very much. then u will know why u get the ACTION_CANCEL event.